# OnEdit function doesn't get range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner to AppScript.
I am developing a code for OnEdit where if A1 cell is true, delete B2 content.
I don't know how to make it work.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != "A1" || e.value == true) return;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetName('Sheet1');
  ss.getRange ('B2').clearContent();      
  e.range.clearContent();
}
```

I've changed the code a bit, but it doesn't work either.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = sh.getSheetByName ("Sheet1");
  if (e.ss.range.getA1Notation() != "A1" || e.value == true) return;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRange ('B2').clearContent();      
  e.range.clearContent();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is event in `A1` might happen in another sheet. To make sure that the event only happens in `Sheet1`, you have the filter it by checking the parent **Sheet** of the event `range`.

The `return;` statement after your `if-statement` will make the script not to read this part of your code if all conditions are met:

```
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRange ('B2').clearContent();      
  e.range.clearContent();
```

Lastly, the `e.value` can only return **String** and not **Boolean**, you have to use 'TRUE'.

Your code should look like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.getA1Notation() == "A1" && sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.value == "TRUE"){
    sheet.getRange ('B2').clearContent();      
    range.clearContent();
  }
}
```

### References:

- [Google Sheet onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Sheet.getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getname)
- [Range.getSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!